# which recovery partition is safe to remove (active, recovery partition) or (recovery partition)?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, recovery-partition

I have two recovery partition and I need to delete one of them. I need to know which recovery the active, recovery partition (400 MB) or recover partition (839 MB) .

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not (be able to) delete the one with `Active`. That's where the Windows Boot Manager and BCD Store are on. Though you can install a new copy of them on `C:` with `bcdboot` and make `C:` the `active` partition with `diskpart` (but not recommended if you do Windows multi-boot and not possible if you enabled BitLocker on `C:`), and then you can delete it after a reboot.

As for whether the other one is safe to delete, you might want to inspect its content (by assigning a drive letter to it with `diskpart`, and make Explorer shows hidden and system files). Though considering its size, it's probably not useful.

I don't suppose it's really useful to delete the first one anyway, since it will be a hassle to move/resize `C:` to use the little freed space. You can easily extend `C:` with the space freed by deleting the second one though.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the following command in an elevated command prompt:

```
reagentc /info
```

to gather information about your recovery environment. It will especially show you on which partition on which harddisk your current recovery partition is located.

You can then safely remove the other partition.

If you also want to remove the active recovery partition, disable your recovery environment from an elevated command prompt first:

```
reagentc /disable
```

and remove the partition afterwards.